# What's the quickest way to write a simple browser client to talk to a REST server

Tags: javascript, client

I'd like to create a simple browser client that I'll to demo the REST API we have implemented on a server. I need basic functionality like

1. Create an item on server using POST: client fills up a few parameters and posts
2. Get list and display using GET: client sends a query, gets an XML list of items and displays them

I don't need any fancy UI, this just for an internal quick demo, a reasonable UI is totally OK.

I know C++, Java, and Perl, but no Javascript. Is JS the easiest way to do this (I am time constrained, have about half a day to implement this)? If so, can you point me to a good resource where I can just pick up the pieces I need?

Comment: I need to display the XML list I get from the server and display it in a somewhat better display than the raw XML display I get with default IE XML display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write javascript and html/css UI to run in a browser, you could use jQuery and its [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) methods.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("your/restful/url/here", function(data) { // do stuff with data here});
    $.post("your/restful/url/here", function(data) { // do stuff with data here});
});
```

You could extend the above even further like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("post").click(function() { 
        $.post("/restful/?parm1=" + $("#input1").val() + "&parm2=" + $("#input2").val() , function(data) { // do stuff with data here});
    });
});

<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="text" id="input2" />
<input type="submit" id="post">Post</input>
```

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you could also just simply use your browser to open your RESTful urls.

Comment: jQuery and JS did help a lot to cook up a simple client, however, the learning curve was a little more steep than I assumed, esp, concerning the same origin policy limitation. I also used jQuery to parse the XML.

Comment: owch - at least you now know about the single origin policy gotcha - today typically you'd use a npm generator to produce the framework of your client and middleware such as http-middleware-proxy to get around the single origin policy. Take a look at following url for more info :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659139/how-to-overcome-access-control-allow-origin-error-when-client-talks-to-server

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the REST server examples (C#, Java, PHP and node.js) I introduced in my [blog](https://restafar.com/).
The good thing about these example is that they all expose XML descriptor of the API that could be used later to generate client libraries in many coding languages using [Kaltura generator](https://github.com/kaltura/clients-generator), including type-script, javascript and other front-end coding languages that may meet your needs.